# Xcode crash when trying to compile Unity3d app to device

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I've successfully compiled another app made in unity3d so it's not that kind of issue. However this app crashes on the line:

```
.byte 1,16,159,231,2,0,160,225,0,224,146,229
```

saying:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

and filling the console with:

```
2012-03-21 15:42:00.560 dice[1205:707] -> registered mono modules 0xbb05ec
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
Mono path[0] = '/var/mobile/Applications/CCF64295-CFD2-4CB6-913F-2317C7D41822/dice.app/Data/Managed'
Renderer: PowerVR SGX 535
Vendor:   Imagination Technologies
Version:  OpenGL ES 2.0 IMGSGX535-63.24
GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_max_level GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc 
Creating OpenGLES2.0 graphics device
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Platform assembly: /var/mobile/Applications/CCF64295-CFD2-4CB6-913F-2317C7D41822/dice.app/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading /var/mobile/Applications/CCF64295-CFD2-4CB6-913F-2317C7D41822/dice.app/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: /var/mobile/Applications/CCF64295-CFD2-4CB6-913F-2317C7D41822/dice.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading /var/mobile/Applications/CCF64295-CFD2-4CB6-913F-2317C7D41822/dice.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: /var/mobile/Applications/CCF64295-CFD2-4CB6-913F-2317C7D41822/dice.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading /var/mobile/Applications/CCF64295-CFD2-4CB6-913F-2317C7D41822/dice.app/Data/Managed/Assembly-UnityScript.dll into Unity Child Domain
- Completed reload, in  0.269 seconds
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
```

And I really don't understand what that's all about, any ideas?

TIA
Markus

edit:
I tried commenting out this part, then it ran, but I need that. What could cause a crash within that code?

```
function OnTriggerEnter( other : Collider ) {
var dieGameObject = GameObject.Find("dice6");
var dieValueComponent : dieValue = dieGameObject.GetComponent(dieValue);
dieValueComponent.currentValue = faceValue;
Debug.Log(faceValue);
}
```

Comment: Sure that dice6 is instantiated already? Can you debug it with the Mono debugger or try to log before each line?

Answer (score 0):

Is your IOS device using the latest IOS version?

Go and Check:

Build Settings -> Base SDK -> Debug & Release IOS version

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the iOS to 8.4 solved the issue for me